# Return p-th powers of each term

Tags: programming

I want to define a function f such that $f(\frac{1+q+qx^2}{1+c+cq})=\frac{1+q^p+q^p x^{2p}}{1+c^p+c^p q^p}$. I think that I can it suffices to define a function g such that $g(x+1+c)=x^p + 1 + c^p$. Hpw could I define g in Mathematica? There are arbitrarily many terms in the polynomials in the domain of g. If there is some function in Mathematica which convert a polynomial to a list, then I know how to define g. Is there some method in Mathematica which converts a polynomial to a List? Thank you very much.

Comment: As asked, you are requesting to define a univariate function that uses information only avaible to a multivariate function.

Comment: Have you seen `CoefficientList[]`?  (Be sure to look at its "Properties & Relatiions" section of the docs for the `FromDigits[]` example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html).

```
ClearAll[f];
f[expr_] := Replace[expr, s_Symbol :> s^p, Infinity, Heads -> False]
```

Then

```
f[(1 + q + q x^2)/(1 + c + c q)]
(* (1 + q^p + q^p x^(2 p))/(1 + c^p + c^p q^p) *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. This would also handle (2 + q + q x^2)

Comment: @Edmund, thank you very much. If there are indices in variables, the results are not what I want. For example, f[x[1,2]+2]=x[1,2]+2. But I want f[x[1,2]+2]=x[1,2]^p+2. How should I modify your codes such that they also work for the variables which have indices?

Comment: @JianrongLi Replace `s_Symbol` with `s : Alternatives @@ Variables@expr`

Comment: @Edmund, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[z_] := Total[(List @@ Numerator[z])^p]/
  Total[(List @@ Denominator[z])^p]

f[(1 + q + q*x^2)/(1 + c + c*q)]

(*  (1 + q^p + (q*x^2)^p)/
   (1 + c^p + (c*q)^p)  *)
```

**EDIT:**  Redefined to address OP's comment

```
Clear[f, g, h]

h[z_] := z /. {
   a_?NumericQ :> a,
   a_?NumericQ expr_ :> a expr^p,
   expr_?(! NumericQ[#] &) :> expr^p}

g[expr_] := Total[h /@ (List @@ expr)]

f[expr_] := Module[
  {denom = Denominator[expr]},
  If [denom === 1,
   g[expr],
   g[Numerator[expr]]/g[denom]]]

f[(1 + q + q*x^2)/(1 + c + c*q)]

(*  (1 + q^p + (q*x^2)^p)/
   (1 + c^p + (c*q)^p)  *)

f[x[1, 2] + 2]

(*  2 + x[1, 2]^p  *)

f[3*x[1, 2] + 2]

(*  2 + 3*x[1, 2]^p  *)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I would like to have f[3*x[1,2]+2]=3*x[1,2]^p+2. How should I modify your code such that f[3*x[1,2]+2]=3*x[1,2]^p+2?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to quickly define the specific `f` in your question, here is the mathematica syntax:

[image]

```
f[(n1_ + q_ + q_ x^2)/(n2_ + c_ + c_ q_)] :=(n1 + q^p + q^p x^(2p))/(n1 + c^p + c^p q^p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice alternative here to `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` is `MapAt`.

```
expr = (1 + q + q x^2)/(2 + c + c q);

MapAt[
 Power[#, p] &, expr,
 Position[expr, _Symbol, Heads -> False]]
```

> `(1 + q^p + q^p x^(2 p))/(2 + c^p + c^p q^p)`

I don't know, should be `2` in the denominator raised to `p` as well?